# Profile2 view with all profile fields

Tags: views, users

How can I create a view, where all profile fields are as columns of a table view, without having to add each profile field indivudally? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this, with a custom module:

```
<?php


/**
 * Implements hook_views_data().
 */
function profile2_all_fields_views_data_alter(&$data) {

  $data['profile']['profile_all_fields'] = array(
    'title' => t('All profile fields'),
    'help' => t('When rendered, this field will be replaced by all the fields on the profile. No configuration is required.'),
    'field' => array(
      'title' => 'All profile fields',
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_custom',
    ),
  );

}

function profile2_all_fields_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args)
{
  // Replace the static field with dynamic fields.
//  dsm($view->display_handler);
//  dsm($view->display_handler->default_display, '$$view->display_handler->default_display');
  if ($view->display_handler->options['fields']) {
    $fields = &$view->display_handler->options['fields'];
  } else {
    $fields = &$view->display_handler->default_display->options['fields'];
  }

  foreach ($fields as $field_name => &$field) {
    if ($field['field'] == 'profile_all_fields') {
      $instances = field_info_instances('profile2', 'main');
      dsm($fields, '$fields');
      // Each field is added as a Views field.
      foreach ($instances as $key => $instance) {
        $newfield['id'] = $instance['field_name'];
        $newfield['table'] = _field_sql_storage_tablename($instance);
        $newfield['field'] = $instance['field_name'];
        $fields[$key] = $newfield;
      }
      unset($fields[$field['id']]);
      dsm($fields, '$fields');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would work if you create a view that displays users as rendered entities, not fields.

You can then tweak the way user entities are rendered and show all fields.

Comment: Yes, that would work. I have forgotten to mention that I want to display the fields as a table in views.